# Logback Keep n Days Logs With Size Based Archiving

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm trying to configure logs rolling policy for a java web application. Here is what I have so far

```
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/appLog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>500MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to keep all the logs for the past 7 days, but compress log files whenever they reach 500MB.

Logback configuration shown above keeps only last 7 files, so if there are lot of logs, I can have 7 files only for the last day, for example.

How can I configure logback in this case to keep all logs for the past 7 days? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What I'm trying to achieve here is to keep all the logs for the past 7
>   days,

Here you specify a pattern that considers a rolling policy until the hour granularity :

```
 <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/appLog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH}.%i.log.gz
```

The `fileNamePattern` is much more than a file name pattern.
It indicates also the rollover frequency.

> The mandatory **fileNamePattern** property defines the name of the
>   rolled-over (archived) log files. Its value should consist of the name
>   of the file, plus a suitably placed **%d** conversion specifier. The %d
>   conversion specifier may contain a date-and-time pattern as specified
>   by the **java.text.SimpleDateFormat** class. If the date-and-time pattern
>   is omitted, then the default pattern **yyyy-MM-dd** is assumed. **The
>   rollover period is inferred from the value of fileNamePattern.**

By specifying this date pattern : `%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH}`, for each day of the year, at each time you log something at a new hour, the actual logs are archived and a new log file is created for the new hour.

For example : all what you log between the `01/03/17 09:00` and the `01/03/17 09:59`are logged in the current log file.
As soon as `01/03/17 10:00`, the first log you will do, will result to a log rotation (archive actual logs in a gz file with the filename pattern specified and clear the current log file).

Besides, as you specify `<maxHistory>7</maxHistory>`, it will archive only 7 distinct hours.
So if your application logs at each hour something, you will archive 7 hours of your application logs and not 7 days as you wish.

**If you want to have logs history for 7 days, just remove the `HH` in the pattern :**

```
 <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/appLog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
```

> but compress log files whenever they reach 500MB.

When in `fileNamePattern` you specify a compression extension as a suffix of the file as gz, zip, etc ... the compression is automatic :

> Note that file compression is also specified via this property. For
>   example, fileNamePattern set to MyLogFile%i.log.zip means that
>   archived files must be compressed using the zip format; gz format is
>   also supported.

And anyway, Logback doesn't provide a way to compress archive only when a specific condition is encountered.
Logs should be compressed or should not.

When you declare this property :

```
 <maxFileSize>500MB</maxFileSize>
```

You specify the max file size by archive.
 
If you don't need to set a limit in the archive size, don't specify it and leave the default value (10MB).

You can retrieve all these information in the [logback appenders documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) :

Comment: I see. Thanks! I forgot that I changed it to hourly rotation. This the issue. It keeps logs for the last 7 hours, not days.

Comment: You are very welcome. The filename pattern is a  little a misleading name as it is much more than a filename pattern.

Comment: Hi @davidxxx, my case is slightly different from this. I want to record the logs for 14 days instead of daily and set the max file size to 50MB. Max file size can be set with `maxFileSize` tag... but I am not sure how to configure the logs to record for 14 days. I am not sure if I really need to create a new thread or question since I think it is somewhat similar to this page/thread question. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello  @Borgy Manotoy, to be clear, do you want to rollover every 14 days or do you want to keep in the history logs not more than 14 days ?

Comment: I want to keep the logs not more than 14 days and set the max size to 50MB

Comment: @Borgy Manotoy Unfortunately, in the https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpFileNamePattern documentation, I don't see any example allowing to fix an arbitrary number of days that doesn't make part of a common time unit (hour, day, week, month, ...).  Maybe asking a question on the logback issues tracking could help you.

Comment: <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/appLog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz -> this applies roll over every day.  for weekly roll over the date pattern is {yyyy-ww}

Answer (score 5):

`<maxHistory>168</maxHistory>` would work in such case(24*7)